# How to express the quantitative difference between the itmes

Tags: grammar

*In a group A there were 20 people and in a group B there were 21.*

How to suitably express the quantitative difference between the groups? Can I say "In a group B there was one man (person) more or "In a group B there was one man (person) in addition“? At first glance a trivial question but I am really not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the groups were of people:

> Group B was larger than Group A *by one person*.

`A was {comparative} than B by {quantifier} {unit of measure [pluralized as necessary]}`

> The sedan was longer than the hatchback by 14 inches.
>
> The new highrise apartments were taller than the old ones by three stories.
>
> The current textbook is shorter than the former by two chapters.
>
> Next month's shipment will be lighter than this one by a few tons.

P.S. If there are supposed to be 21 people in the group, as there are supposed to be 52 cards in a deck, but one is missing:

> The group was shy one person.
>
> The deck was shy two jacks.
>
> The deck had one ace too many.

Comment: You said nothing about a *required* number in your question. But see the P.S.

Comment: I see nothing here about what seems to me the most idiomatic construction for OP's context: *Group B has **one more person** than Group A*. Speaking for myself, I find *Group B has **one person more** than Group A* somewhat clunky by comparison. And *You should buy this one - it costs **one less pound** than the other* seems positively "ungrammatical" to me, though I can't say exactly why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OP's context is not perfectly clear by any means, and OP has removed a comment to which I was responding above, where he had asked about "shy". Your example, with **costs**, introduces something to the context which was not present in the OP's question.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be easy to find corpus research supporting my position here, but I still think *Group B was **one** [person] **larger** than Group A* would be far more common than *Group B was larger than Group A **by one** [person]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Please feel free to add an answer. Your version is certainly viable. "a few tons lighter" or "lighter by a few tons" are both idiomatic.  But "a mile faster" and "faster by a mile" are not equally viable.

Comment: I'm certainly not claiming that usages such as [*cheaper **by a few pence***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cheaper+by+a+few+pence%22) are "non-idiomatic". But that gets just 6 hits in Google Books, compared to an estimated 258 hits for [***a few pence** cheaper*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+few+pence+cheaper%22). As for your "mile" example though, I'd say the idiomatic (metaphorical) standard is *This one is **miles better*** (or maybe *It's better by miles* or even *It's better by a mile*, but almost never *It's **a mile** better*).